# get the contact name from contacts in android

Tags: android, contacts

I am having a problem with getting contact name from contacts. I am making an SMS application and as you know, when you receive a SMS the number you receive comes with country code, but if same number you have saved in your memory without country code how would you find it?

I can get the number if it is saved with country code but cannot if it is saved without country code.

Here is my code:

```
String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };

    // encode the phone number and build the filter URI
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));

    // query time
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null,
            null, null);

    // if the query returns 1 or more results
    // return the first result
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        String name = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        return name;
    }

    // return the original number if no match was found
    return number;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use [SQLite LIKE](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php) in your selection. I have not tested this, but you will get the idea. The method accepts number(address) from SMS and tries to map it to number from Phone.NUMBER.

```
  private void whateverYouCallMe(String numberWithCode) {

  String[] projection = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };

  String selection = Phone.NUMBER + " LIKE '%?%'" // numberWithCode should supplement the ? 
  final String[] SELECTION_ARGS = { numberWithCode };

  Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, selection, SELECTION_ARGS, null);

  //etc
  }
```

Comment: i tried this but still no results. should i use a query with or opertaor. querying number with code and without code?..

Comment: damn, I forgot to add the selection arguments. Added now

Comment: Now its crashing on me because of this selection argument. you have not specified the statement of ContactURI. i added this

  Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));

and the error i am getting is : bind or column index out of range.

Comment: I think you need to use ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI

Comment: got the answer working by changing string to " LIKE ?" instead of " LIKE '%?%'"